# How to Repeat a Row on All Pages When Printing in Excel js- row to repat at top in exceljs

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, excel, exceljs

I want to use the following option, or something similar, in the Excel Js library
[image]

This option repeats a row when printing on all pages.

I know it is possible to freeze a row in Excel Js but I want a row to be repeated on all pages when printing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this question is the following code:

```
worksheet.pageSetup.printTitlesColumn = "1:1";
```

You may want to place more rows on each page.

for example for 3 row of top write this string for **printTitlesColumn**  propperty:

```
worksheet.pageSetup.printTitlesColumn = "1:3";
```